# how to color in 'wave' procedural texture (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'd like to add color to a 'wave' procedural texture.

Other procedural textures come with color options (like cheker e.g.) but this one doesn't.
I am new to the Cycles rendering engine and I don't know how to use nodes or combine them.

Is there a way to mix this with another shader so i get a colored procedural texture?

Comment: How about a colour ramp between the texture and the shader?

Comment: How is that done? @SixthOfFour

Comment: I believe @BlendingJake just gave you the answer. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this by putting the `Color` or `Fac` output of the texture through a `Color Ramp Node` and adjusting the colors and positions of the markers. This works both for **Cycles** and **Blender Render**
*Cycles*
[image]
*Blender Render*
[image]